# database one to many and one to one relation

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following tables
products
category
subCategory
Some products will have no subCategory.
With my current design I have a one to many relationship between category and subCategory.
At this moment I have a 'no subCategory' value for every category. 
My question:
Is it possible to have a single 'no subCategory' row in the subCategory table instead of multiple instances I have now ?

One way to do this would be to have the first row of subCategory hold the 'no subCategory' value and write a sql that selects that first row together with the subCategory data associated with the category.

Comment: Perhaps if you clarify, for yourself, and for us, what your tables look like, and what the relations are, you can answer your own question? Try something like this: https://dbdesigner.net and then show us the result.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over complicate it. If a product has a sub-category then have a sub-category record. If it doesn't have a sub-category then don't have a record.

Comment: Why didn't I think about this.? Thank you very much.